# Get 1 if Value exists with date

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-server-2016

I have two tables
Table 1

| PersonalNr | other Values |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 2 |  |

Table 2

| Personalnr | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-09-1 |
| 2 | 2023-09-1 |
| 2 | 2023-09-2 |

I want to have a select that gives me a table that sets a 1 if an entry for that day is there and a 0 if not.
Expected would be

| PersonalNr | 2023-09-01 | 2023-09-02 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |

I tried the following but did not get the correct 1 and 0.

```
    SELECT t1.personalnr,
      case when EXISTS (  select* from table2 
        where date between '2023-01-09' and '2023-02-09' and t1.personalnr = t2.personalnr) then '1' else '0'
      end
case when EXISTS (  select* from table2 
    where date between '2023-02-09' and '2023-03-09' and t1.personalnr = t2.personalnr) then '1' else '0'
  end
    FROM [BKLatWORK].[dbo].[Table1] t1
    left join table2 t2 on t2.PersonalNr = t1.PersonalNr
    group by t1.PersonalNr, t2.personalnr
```

Comment: What's expected to happen if someone inserts the row (1, '2023-10-20') into table2? Should it be ignored, or do you want a new column added to the result?

Comment: it could be ignored. I want to build a view for september and would do a new one for october

Comment: But for '2023-09-20' you want a new column?

Comment: Add a tag for the dbms you're using. I assume product specific features might be handy here.

Comment: added tag and yes the column should be added than

Comment: SQL Server, check out `PIVOT`.

Comment: why would you need two views - one for September and another for October?! That doesn't sound like a good way of coding why not on the procedure or a view where you can pass dates and get the output?
You would need a dynamic pivot query or a dynamic query to create row values as columns and in this it is the dates that should appear in the columns

Comment: you can check out the code https://dbfiddle.uk/RPYflrKM 

I created a dynamic Pivot query to achieve what you wanted and having two different views for two months is not an ideal way of coding. 
There is a print statement at the end, so you can view the actual query that uses 
the dates provided in the 'startDate' and 'endDate' date variables

Answer (score 2):

You can use the conditional aggregation, if you are not looking for a dynamic solution :

```
select t1.Personalnr, 
       MAX(case when t2.Date = '2023-09-01' then 1 else 0 end) as [2023-09-01],
       MAX(case when t2.Date = '2023-09-02' then 1 else 0 end) as [2023-09-02]
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t1.Personalnr = t2.Personalnr
group by t1.Personalnr
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/dSPlL6cG)

Comment: `MAX` *might* be a better option here, as *if* there are multiple rows for a single date then you could end up with 2+ as the returned value.

Comment: Also don't use single quotes (`'`) for aliases. Single quotes are for literal strings, not delimit identifying object names. They can also result in some "gotchas" as their behaviour is not consistent depending on where they are referenced. Also some syntaxes with literal string aliases are deprecated. Stick to object and alias names that don't need delimit identifying, and if you *must* delimit identify them use T-SQL's identifier, brackets (`[]`), or ANSI-SQL's, double quotes (`"`).

Comment: Thanks @ThomA, Yes `MAX` is better since the OP need to know if the entry is there or not

Answer (score 0):

This could also be a good use case for a pivot table.
I've created a Calendar_Table with all the dates for the year 2023, that I will use almost as an auxiliary table to be able to pivot my data, regardless if the employees have data for a particular date in table2.
For that I've created the Calendar_Table using a recursive CTE as bellow:

```
WITH Calendar_CTE AS (
  SELECT CAST('20230101' AS DATE) AS [Date]
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, [Date]) FROM Calendar_CTE
  WHERE DATEADD(DAY, 1, [Date]) < '20240101'
)
SELECT *
INTO Calendar_Table
FROM Calendar_CTE
ORDER BY [Date]
OPTION (maxrecursion 0)
```

Then I use some dynamic SQL to be able to aggregate and pivot the data for a range of dates that I define in the 3rd and 4th line.

```
DECLARE @tsql VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @pivot_columns VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @start_date DATE = '20230901'
DECLARE @end_date DATE = '20230905'
DECLARE @c_date DATE

DECLARE dates_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT [Date]
FROM Calendar_Table
WHERE
  [Date] >= @start_date
  AND
  [Date] <= @end_date

OPEN dates_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM dates_cursor INTO @c_date
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
  SET @pivot_columns += '[' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@c_date, 23) + '],'
  FETCH NEXT FROM dates_cursor INTO @c_date
END
CLOSE dates_cursor
DEALLOCATE dates_cursor

SET @pivot_columns = LEFT(@pivot_columns, LEN(@pivot_columns) - 1)

SET @tsql += 'SELECT
  PersonalNr,' + @pivot_columns

SET @tsql += '
FROM
(
SELECT
  T1.PersonalNr,
  CT.[Date],
  COUNT(*) AS ct
FROM
  table1 AS T1
LEFT JOIN
  table2 AS T2
  ON T1.PersonalNr = T2.PersonalNr
RIGHT JOIN
  Calendar_Table AS CT
  ON T2.Date = CT.Date
GROUP BY
  T1.PersonalNr, CT.[Date]
) AS Source_Table
PIVOT
(
  COUNT(ct)
  FOR [Date] IN (' + @pivot_columns + ')
) AS Pivot_Table
WHERE
PersonalNr IS NOT NULL'

EXEC (@tsql)
```

| PersonalNr | 2023-09-01 | 2023-09-02 | 2023-09-03 | 2023-09-04 | 2023-09-05 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

[demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/k_tfHqGs?hide=22)

This approach, albeit more complicated than the one described above, gives me a couple benefits:

- It let me dynamically filter the data for the time period that I want
- I don't have to manually write aggregations for every single day that I want to see in my result/report/wherever
- I can easily modify the query, as it will not be bigger the more dates I want to see

That being said, I'm not completely happy using a cursor, there are probably better ways to do it and avoid the cursor. But given that the dataset that the cursor will be looping on is very small, I didn't really care about it. But still... It can be better.

I hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

About this answer:
1: It does not account for any SQL injection vulnerabilities.  It is a demonstration of a single solution.  Do not use this code in any production system without understanding SQL injection vulnerabilities.
2: It does not use cursors or the PIVOT function in sql server.
3: This was done with SQL Server 2022

```
--  procedurally create a pivot table without PIVOT function and without CURSORS

-- make sure we start with a clean slate
drop table if exists #unique_dates  -- this holds unique personal nr dates to use as columns
drop table if exists #result  
drop table if exists #personal_nr
drop table if exists #personal_nr_date

create table #personal_nr  -- OP table - assumes primary key
(
    personal_nr int not null primary key
)

create table #personal_nr_date  -- OP table - assumes primary key
(
    personal_nr int not null,
    date_created date not null,
    primary key (personal_nr, date_created)
)

create table #result
(
    personal_nr int not null primary key
)

create table #unique_dates
(
    date_created date not null,
    rownum int not null
)

-- insert test data reflecting OP's data
insert into #personal_nr
select  1 union all 
select  2 union all
select  3 union all
select  4 union all
select  5 union all
select  6 union all
select  7

insert into #personal_nr_date
select  1, '2023-09-01' union all
select  2, '2023-09-01' union all
select  3, '2023-09-01' union all
select  4, '2023-09-01' union all
select  5, '2023-09-01' union all
select  6, '2023-09-01' union all
select  2, '2023-09-02' union all
select  3, '2023-09-02' union all
select  4, '2023-09-02' union all
select  5, '2023-09-02' union all
select  6, '2023-09-02' union all
select  1, '2023-09-03' union all
select  6, '2023-09-03' union all
select  7, '2023-09-03'


-- prime the result table with personal_nr values - order by is not required
insert into #result
select  p.personal_nr
from    #personal_nr p  
order by    p.personal_nr


-- we want to store the unique dates with a row number to use with looping
insert into #unique_dates
select  ud.date_created,
        ROW_NUMBER() over (order by ud.date_created) as rownum      
from    #personal_nr_date ud
group by    ud.date_created
order by    ud.date_created asc


-- declare vars for our loop
declare @num_loops int = (select count(1) from #unique_dates)
declare @i int = 1
declare @date_as_column nvarchar(12) = null
declare @previous_date_as_column nvarchar(10) = null
declare @date_var date = null
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = null


-- loop to build out the result table and add to it our personal_nr values
while @i <= @num_loops
    begin
        
        -- get our date column value and store the date for comparison later
        select  @date_as_column = format(udate.date_created, 'yyyy-MM-dd'),
                @date_var = udate.date_created
        from    #unique_dates udate
        where   udate.rownum = @i
        

        -- create dynamic sql to alter the temp table to add the column and values 
        -- NOTICE the default 0 - we update that value if we need to down below
        set @sql =  'alter table #result
                     add '+ quotename(@date_as_column) +' bit not null default 0'
        
        -- uncomment if you want to see the sql 
        -- select @sql
        exec(@sql)
        
        
        -- set 1 for personal_nr values with this date
        set @sql = 'update  r
                    set     r.' + quotename(@date_as_column) +' = 1
                    from    #result r
                                inner join
                            #personal_nr_date d on
                                    r.personal_nr = d.personal_nr
                    where   format(d.date_created, ''yyyy-MM-dd'') = ''' + format(@date_var, 'yyyy-MM-dd') + ''''
        
        exec(@sql)              
        
        -- uncomment if you want to see the sql
        -- select @sql
                                                
        -- increment our loop var
        set @i = @i + 1
    end

    select * from #result


-- do not forget to clean up our mess!                  
drop table if exists #unique_dates  
drop table if exists #result  
drop table if exists #personal_nr
drop table if exists #personal_nr_date
```

[image]